# R v3.3.0 on a 64-bit windows m/c with 18GB RAM - Memory issues while loading a dataframe to excel

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, xlconnect

I'm new to the world of R, so, please bear with me if the question is naive.

Issue: I'm trying to load a bunch of data frames into different sheets of the same excel document. Each data frame has about 400-500K objects with around 60-70 variables.I've tried using different packages like `XLConnect` and `openxlsx` to perform this task but, they  every package spikes up the memory to the `MAX` (R uses up around 13 GB; Max available - 18GB) and ends up failing. Ut works when I load each dataframe individually. I understand that R first saves these dataframes on memory and then dumps it into an excel file, but I don't understand why it would use up all the available memory. The excel file with all the dataframes loaded is still a mere 500MB file.

I used the below using XLConnect:

```
writeWorksheetToFile("test.xlsx", data = list(X, Y), sheet = c("X", "Y"))
```

P.S I'm running a 3.3.0 version of R on a 64-bit Windows Server 2012 with 18GB of RAM.

Comment: xlsx files are zip files. the fact that it's 500meg on the drive is irrelevant. it's still compressed data, and you may actually have 10+ gigs of numerical data in there.

Comment: Are you trying to _load_ an Excel sheet into R, or _save_ an R data frame to a worksheet?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to save an R dataframe to a worksheet. Is there anyway I can clear up the memory used proactively?